# Angular OpenLayers not showing custom pointer feature

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm trying to make a pinpoint for a map with openlayers and openstreetmap in angular but the pinpoint does not show.

The map however does get displayed and is funtional.
To display the map itself I first encountered the issue that the width and height needed to be altered in css, maybe this is the same? But I do not know how I would need to style the layer.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj.js';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import {Icon, Style} from 'ol/style';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  map;
  testp;
  vectorSource;
  vectorLayer;
  rasterLayer;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testp = new Feature({
      geometry: new Point(fromLonLat([3.7219431, 51.054633]))
    });

    this.testp.setStyle(new Style({
      image: new Icon(({
        color: '#8959A8',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        src: '../assets/car-parking.svg',
        imgSize: [20, 20]
      }))
    }));

    this.vectorSource = new VectorSource({
      features: [this.testp]
    });

    this.vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: this.vectorSource
    });

    this.map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [ new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
      }), this.vectorLayer ],
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([3.7219431, 51.054633]),
        zoom: 15,
      })
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be an issue with the path to your icon. This worked for me:

```
import Style from 'ol/style/Style';
import Icon from 'ol/style/Icon';

...

this.testp.setStyle(new Style({
  image: new Icon(({
    color: '#8959A8',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    src: 'assets/car-parking.svg',
    imgSize: [20, 20]
  }))
}));
```

Comment: odd, I changed it but it does not work for me, could it be something else? in another file? I'm also pretty new to angular

Comment: Mmh. Your code looks fine so far and it also worked for me. Hard to say why it does not work for you as well. Do you get any other errors?

Comment: I do not get any errors, the markers just do not show on the map.

Comment: Do you have `"assets": ["src/favicon.png", "src/assets"]` in your angular.json?

Comment: yeah, they are there.

Comment: Do you see a point on your map after removing your image style?

Comment: Damn yeah it works, without the styling I see the point. would it be the svg or the path to it?

Comment: Alright. Then it must be the style or the svg itself. Can you try another svg?

Comment: it was the SVG, changed it and it works. Thanks a lot for your time and effort!!!

Comment: Glad I could help you :)